# Tag-only edits, refuse or accept?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, suggested-edits

I've searched `tag edits` here on meta but found nothing.

I now have to ability to accept/refuse user edits. Most of those I saw are users which just modifies the tag of a question. Should I accept those edits or refuse them as `too minor`?

Comment: Tip for finding duplicates: do a Google search with *site:meta.stackoverflow.com* in your query. You'll often get better results.

Comment: Good question; the question I've marked this as duplicate should help there.

Comment: so... yeah. I should accept them if the tag is relevant. Thanks!